# Is it possible to make bones not show "In Front" of everything when in Pose Mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

I was hoping for my rig to not display in front of everything when in Pose Mode to reduce visual clutter. I've created control shapes that neatly fit around my deforming character so I don't need to see it through everything.
I've unchecked "In Front" in the Armature Tab under Viewport Display. This works while in object mode, but not in Pose Mode. I'm using 2.9 by the way.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was unable to recreate this issue in a new separate file, I decided to start a new file, and append the main collections. The problem is not there anymore, and all the scene data including skinning data is intact thankfully.

EDIT: I've found the cause. It's not a bug or anything. I had somehow activated Bone X-Ray in the shading menu of Pose Mode, which I wasn't aware of

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you unchecked BOTH "In Front" options?

Unless 2.9 has changed in that aspect relative to 2.82, you should have one in the **Armature tab** and one in the **Object tab.**
[image]

Either way, supposing it's a bug or something weird that you can't fix, you can always duplicate your viewport window and Uncheck Overlays - it removes the bones and leaves only the mesh so you can fiddle with the armature on the original window, and look at the other without any clutter, in real time.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've unchecked it on both (In 2.9, both switches are connected and switch off together). So I guess that's a bug then. At least it's good to know that it's possible. Thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem!
Yeah, it's probably a bug. You should check the bug reports, perhaps it's new and must be reported.
But then again, if it hasn't happened again on the new file, there's nothing to report, so forget about it!